# case class copy with multiple Options

Tags: scala

In scala, case classes are immutable.
What is the best way to make a modified copy of a case class with several options?

eg:

```
case class Person(name:String, age:Int, something:Option[String])

val maybeName = Some("alice")
val maybeAge = Some(20)
val maybeSomething = Some("hi")

var myNewCaseClass = myCaseClass.???
```

Comment: What is the behaviour if `maybeName` or `maybeAge` are `None`?

Comment: No update occurs.  Use case is a User supplied form to update the case class.

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you want to do:

```
val myNewCaseClass: Option[Person] = for {
  name <- maybeName
  age <- maybeAge
} yield Person(name, age, maybeSomething)
```

Comment: This will not update the age unless the name is also given.

Comment: I think it's the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

One awkward way is to use getOrElse for each property on `myCaseClass` with the original value.
When the case class's val is an option, you can use .orElse (thanks to Thilo)

```
val myNewCaseClass = myCaseClass.copy(
    name = maybeName.getOrElse(myCaseClass.name),
    age = maybeAge.getOrElse(myCaseClass.age),
    something = maybeSomething.orElse(myCaseClass.something)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any nice way to do it as you want...

```
val v1 = maybeAge.map(age => myCaseClass.copy(age = age)).getOrElse(myCaseClass)
val v2 = maybeName.map(name => v1.copy(name = name).getOrElse(v1)
val v3 = maybeSomething.map(something => v2.copy(something = something)).getOrElse(v2)
```